# How does unevaluatedProperties interact with nested properties?

Tags: jsonschema

Given the following JSON schema:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {}
  },
  "unevaluatedProperties": false
}
```

Is this instance valid?

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz"
  }
}
```

Some validation libraries I tried give different results. The correct behavior is a bit unclear to me, and I haven't seen it explicitly addressed anywhere.

I haven't really grasped how annotation collection works, so should the annotation for `bar` "bubble up" through `foo` to the root so that `unevaluatedProperties` would be applied to it, or is it only direct children that should be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `unevaluatedProperties` specification: "The behavior of this keyword depends on the annotation results of **adjacent** keywords that apply to the instance location being validated. Specifically, the annotations from "properties", "patternProperties", and "additionalProperties", which can come from those keywords
when they are adjacent to the "unevaluatedProperties" keyword." [More here](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#name-unevaluatedproperties)

This means the keyword does not look "into" sub-schemas and your sample is valid.